# Why readValueUnderLock(e) exist in ConcurrentHashMap’s get method?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

When I read the source code of `ConcurrentHashMap` at `JDK1.6`, I found that `readValueUnderLock(e)` can't be reached, because the put method has checked the value: if value is null, it must throw `NullPointerException`. So I think there may be something wrong but i'm not sure what it is. I'll be grateful if someone can answer me!

some source code here:

```
V get(Object key, int hash) {
    if (count != 0) { // read-volatile
        HashEntry<K,V> e = getFirst(hash);
        while (e != null) {
            if (e.hash == hash && key.equals(e.key)) {
                V v = e.value;
                if (v != null)
                    return v;
                return readValueUnderLock(e); // recheck
            }
            e = e.next;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

V readValueUnderLock(HashEntry<K,V> e) {
    lock();
    try {
        return e.value;
    } finally {
        unlock();
    }
}

public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (value == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    return segmentFor(hash).put(key, hash, value, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V is just a snapshot of the Entry.value. The Entry may not be fully constructed yet (consider the double-check lock issue in previous Java Memory Model) and it could be null. While this is just a extreme edge case, JRE has to make sure this works, so there is your `readValueUnderLock`.

PS: It's better to keep up with the time. Java is evolving and Java 9 is coming in several months. There has been some tremendous changes in its codebase. Filling up your head with obsolete knowledge may not be a good idea.

Comment: There's nothing obsolete about `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Yes that's not obsolete but its internal implementation has changed a lot. You can't find `HashEntry` or `Segment` in CHM in Java 8. Any knowledge about CHM internals in Java 6 is obsolete and hacks used may not be needed or corrrect in later java versions. You will need it if you firmly believes your client only need Java6 and will never decide to upgrade it, which isn't the common case.

Comment: I know `double-check` - one of the implementation of `singleton pattern`. Without keyword `volatile`, the instance is not null, and also is not a right value(it not be fully constructed yet). You mean that `readValueUnderLock` play a same role as volatile(effect after JDK1.6) here?

Comment: Yes, because that array storing hash enties isn't a `AtomicReferenceArray` and its read-write access isn't that safe.

Comment: THX a lot, I get it.